# Subscriptable objects in class

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, subscript

I have a `Python 3.4.3` class called `Sparse` in order to represent sparse matrices and operations among them.

Along with this class I have function definitions including how to overload the addition operation, print function etc. However, these functions are written when the sparse matrices were represented as dictionaries with keys representing the position of non-zero entries and corresponding non-zero entry as the value.

The functions work fine in this prior implementation, yet when the sparse matrices are implemented as a class this approach fails yielding a

```
TypeError: ` 'Sparse' object is not subscriptable`.
```

How can I circumvent this issue? I am attaching the relevant code for reference purposes. The **error traceback** is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sparse_driver.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(s)
  File "/mnt/DATA/Dropbox/Courses/Python/HW4/SparseClass.py", line 42, in __str__
    sparse_functions.sparse_print(self)
  File "/mnt/DATA/Dropbox/Courses/Python/HW4/sparse_functions.py", line 56, in sparse_print
    nrow = a['-1'][0]
TypeError: 'Sparse' object is not subscriptable
```

**Function definitions**

```
import random
# Deepcopy is imported in order not to change the matrix a itself
from copy import deepcopy
def sparse_gen(num_row, num_col, spar):
    # Total number of elements
    nelem = num_row * num_col
    # Number of nonzero elements
    n_nonzero = int(nelem * spar)
    # Position of nonzero elements
    poselem = random.sample(range(nelem), n_nonzero)
    # Create an empty dictionary here
    spardict = {};
    # Add entries into the dictionary here  in a for loop
    for i in range(len(poselem)):
        # Create a string from the number in poselem and use it as a key
        key = str(poselem[i])
        # Select -1 or 1  randomly
        spardict[key]  = random.choice([-1,1])
    # Add the size of the matrix with the key value -1
    spardict['-1'] = [num_row, num_col]
    # Return the sparse matrix for reference later on
    return spardict
# Here is the function for addition of two matrices
def sparse_add(a, b):
    # First lets check if the matrix sizes are equal or not
    if a['-1'] != b['-1'] :
        print('Matrix sizes should be equal. Exiting!')
        return
    # Copy matrix a into matrix c the sum a + b = c
    c = deepcopy(a)
    # Delete the size info from  b and retrieve the keys
    del b['-1']
    bkeys = b.keys()
    # Write the for loop for summation iterating over keys of b
    for bkey in iter(bkeys):
        if (bkey in a):
            if ((c[bkey] + b[bkey]) == 0):
                del c[bkey]
                continue
            else:
                c[bkey] += b[bkey]
        else:
                c[bkey] = b[bkey]
    # Since it gives rise to problems later readd b['-1']
    b['-1'] = a['-1']
    return c
# The function for printing sparse matrices is defined here
def sparse_print(a):
    # Lets retrieve the size information first (rows, columns)
    # Remember the size information is a list
    nrow = a['-1'][0]
    ncol = a['-1'][1]
    # Lets write a for loop to print out the relevant info
    for i in range(nrow * ncol):
        # if the i is in a print that value otherwise print 0
        return_str = ""
        if str(i) in a:
            return_str += "%3d " %  a[str(i)]
        else:
            return_str += "%3d " % 0
        # Print new line if we hit the end of the row
        if ((i + 1) % nrow) == 0:
            return_str += "\n"
    return_str += "\n\n"# Two new line characters to avoid confusion
    return return_str
# The function for converting sparse matrices to full is defined here
def mat2sparse(a):
    spardict = {}
    num_row = len(a)
    num_col = len(a[0])
    nelem = num_row * num_col
    # Input the size information
    spardict['-1'] = [num_row, num_col]
    for i in range(num_row):
        for j in range(num_col):
            if a[i][j] != 0:
                # Calculate the position of the key
                key = str(i*num_col + j)
                spardict[key] = a[i][j]
    return spardict
```

**Class Definition**

```
import sparse_functions
class GetAttr(type):
    def __getitem__(cls, x):
        return getattr(cls, x)
class Sparse:
    __metaclass__ = GetAttr
    """ Class for sparse matrices"""
    # This is the constructor when dimensions and sparsity are specified
    def __init__(self, *args):
        # The name of the helper function is sparse_gen
        if len(args) == 3:
            num_row = args[0]
            num_col = args[1]
            spar = args[2]
            if ((type(args[0]) is not int) or (type(args[1]) is not int)):
                raise TypeError('The first two arguments should be integers!')
            elif not ((args[0] > 0) and (args[1] > 0)):
                raise ValueError('The first two agruments should be positive!')
            elif not ((args[2] < 1) and (args[2] > 0)):
                raise ValueError('Sparsity must be between 0 and 1!')
            self.sparse_rep = sparse_functions.sparse_gen(num_row, num_col, spar)
        elif len(args) == 1:
            if (type(args[0] is not list)):
                raise TypeError('The only argument supplied should be a list!')
            # The list of lists matrix is provided convert it to sparse
            self.sparse_rep = sparse_functions.mat2sparse(arg[0])
        else:
            raise AttributeError('Invalid number of arguments. There should be either one argument or three arguments!')
    # Overload the addition operation
    def __add__(a,b):
        # Here we can make use of the already defined functions
        return sparse_functions.sparse_add(a,b)
    # Overload the subtraction operator
    def __sub__(a,b):
        return sparse_functions.sparse_add(a,-b)
    # Overload the print function
    def __str__(self):
        sparse_functions.sparse_print(self)
```

**Driver**

```
import random
from SparseClass import *
s=Sparse(4,4,0.2)
p=Sparse(4,4,0.3)
# Both of the following lines are problematic
print(s)
s + p
```

[Functions](http://pastebin.com/1JKyghJw)

[Class Definition](http://pastebin.com/y299d3eq)

[Driver](http://pastebin.com/m5tbZ1gU)

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Put all relevant information in the question itself; do not use links to off-site resources.

Comment: `a['-1'][0]` you are using a string to index a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is you're confusing the use of *Meta Classes* (classes are *their instances*) with that of *Super Classes* (classes are their *sub-classes*).

Meta Classes act on classes, indicated by the fact that the methods they define (like `__getitem__`) have a parameter which we conventionally indicate as a class by : `__getitem__(cls, index)`.

When assigning a custom metaclass on a user-defined class, instances of the user-defined class won't use methods defined in the custom metaclass, their classes do.

This is in contrast with Super Classes, from which we *inherit* methods applicable on instances of a user-defined class.

Without getting in the implementation of what you're trying to do, I'll give a small example to demonstrate this (using Py3.5) and I'm hoping you'll get the gist of it.

First, a base Metaclass defining `__getitem__()`:

```
class MetaCls(type):
   def __getitem__(cls, index):
       print("Using meta __getitem__ on classes that have my type"
```

This acts *on all classes* that have a `__metaclass__ = MetaCls`, if we define our `Base` Class as using `MetaCls` we can see that this works on `classes` **but not on instances of these classes**:

```
# metaclass is defined in header:
class Base(metaclass=MetaCls):
    pass

# works on classes
Base[0]
Using meta __getitem__ on classes that have my type

base_instance = Base()

# fails on instances
base_instance[0]  # TypeError!
```

In order to make subscription work on instances too, we need to define the appropriate `Super Class` from which we can subclass or, overload our `__getitem__` method in class `Base`:

```
class SuperBase:
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        print("Using SuperBase __getitem__ on instances that derive from classes that subclass me")

class Base(SuperBase, metaclass=MetaCls):
    pass
```

Now, `__getitem__` works on both classes **and** instances, for classes it uses `MetaCls.__getitem__(cls, index)` while for instances it uses `SuperBase.__getitem__(self, index)`:

```
Base[0]  # meta invocation
Using meta __getitem__ on classes that have my type

base_instance = Base()

base_instance[0]  # super invocation
Using SuperBase __getitem__ on instances that derive from classes that subclass me
```

---

In the end, not sure why exactly you considered defining a custom meta in this case since a Super Class seems more suitable but I'm hoping you have your reasons.

Either way, even if you do define a Super Class with the overloaded `__getitem__` this is really going to result in another error:

Keeping the rest as you have pasted them and just adding a superclass instead of a metaclass:

```
print(d) # Raises the following error:

      1 class GetAttr:
      2     def __getitem__(self, index):
----> 3         return getattr(self, index)
      4 class Sparse(GetAttr):
      5     """ Class for sparse matrices"""

AttributeError: 'Sparse' object has no attribute '-1'
```

This makes sense; `print(d)` will result to call to `nrow = a['-1'][0]` which will invoke `__getitem__` with an instance of `Sparce` and `index= -1`.

`__getitem__`, as it is programmed will then try and fetch an attribute named `-1` from your class `Sparce`, this obviously does not exist.

I would suggest maybe overloading `__getitem__` in the `Sparce` class and *inside* `__getitem__` performing some indexing operation on an array-like object in your instance. (probably `self.sparse_rep` ?)

Answer (score 2):

> ...this approach fails yielding a TypeError of 'Sparse' object is not
>   subscriptable. How can I circumvent this issue?

By using `inheritance`:

```
class GetAttr:
    def __getitem__(cls, x):
        return getattr(cls, x)

class Sparse(GetAttr):
    x = 10

s = Sparse()
print(s['x'])

--output:--
10
```

By the way, in `python3.4` the `__metaclass__` line:

```
class Dog:
    __metaclass__ = SomeClass
```

does nothing. I have to write:

```
class Dog(metaclass=SomeClass):
```

Some points about `metaclasses`:

1. When you specify SomeClass as the metaclass, SomeClass is called to create the Dog class.
2. The Dog class will be the return value of the metaclass's `__new__()` method.
3. Other methods in the metaclass are not inherited.

Here is an example:

```
class MyMetaClass(type):
    def stop(self):
        print('I will stop.')

    def __new__(cls, name, parents, dct):
        dct["start"] = lambda self: print('I will start\n.')  #See explanation below
        return super().__new__(cls, name, parents, dct)

class Dog(metaclass=MyMetaClass):
    pass

d = Dog()
d.start()
d.stop()

--output:--
I will start.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 14, in <module>
    d.stop()
AttributeError: 'Dog' object has no attribute 'stop'
```

Note that in Python objects are implemented as `dictionaries`, which means an instance has a dictionary where variables are stored, and a class has a dictionary where methods and variables are stored.  In the code above, `dct` will be the class dictionary for the newly created class, and inside `__new__()` you can store things in the class dictionary and then they will be available in the new class.

The above example raises the possibility of doing this to your metaclass:

```
class MyMetaClass(type):
    def __getitem__(cls, x):
        return getattr(cls, x)

    def __new__(cls, name, parents, dct):
        dct["__getitem__"] = cls.__getitem__   #<*****HERE
        return super().__new__(cls, name, parents, dct)


class Dog(metaclass=MyMetaClass):
    x = 10

d = Dog()
print(d['x'])

--output:--
10
```

A class's `__init__()` method can be used to initialize an instance of a class, and similarly a metaclass's `__new__()` method can be used to initialize a *class*.